# Что значит "добавить изменения в upstream"?

Tags: терминология

Что значит "добавить изменения в upstream"?

Контекст:

> У нас используется Hibernate, причём Hibernate свой, форкнутый.
>   Почему?.. Потому что, во-первых, не все изменения легко добавить в
>   upstream. То есть, вам нужно запилить какую-то фичу, и совсем
>   необязательно, что community примет её спокойно. Вам оно нужно, а
>   больше никому оно не нужно.

[Ссылка на источник](https://youtu.be/ymXqi5KCEd4?t=7m50s)

Comment: Какой контекст?

Comment: @D-side, добавила контекст

Comment: [In software development, upstream refers to a direction toward the original authors or maintainers of software that is distributed as source code, and is a qualification of either a bug or a patch.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_\(software_development\))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> У нас используется Hibernate, причём Hibernate свой, **форкнутый**.

Процесс **форка** это, в сущности, создание собственного репозитория (Б) на основе существующего (А) с целью добавить к продукту какие-то собственные изменения.

Так вот (Б) это форк, а (А) это upstream.

Создатель форка может быть никак не связан с создателями проекта, и обычно может вносить изменения в форк, но не в upstream. В upstream может только **предлагать** (если, конечно, не является одним из сопровождающих, но об этом далее).

Поддержкой upstream же занимаются мэйнтейнеры (сопровождающие) проекта. Их версия является "канонической", и все изменения, которые они принимают, обычно в конечном счёте попадают в форки, которые от них зависят. В этом смысле они "выше по течению": те изменения, что они принимают, "растекаются вниз" по форкам**. Отсюда и название.

В целом, эти термины характеризуют определённый вид отношений между двумя репозиториями. Это необязательно должны быть два серверных репозитория. Эти термины применимы и к ситуации, когда у вас есть локальный клон репозитория с сервера. Репозиторий на сервере это upstream, а у вас, в некотором смысле, форк.

---

** ...но только тем, что следуют за upstream. Так бывает не всегда. Некоторые форки создаются с идеей идти в другую сторону, изменения из upstream они могут получать избирательно или не получать вовсе.  Но таких форков меньшинство.